# Disable next button in multi-step form until fields validate

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-mobile, client-side

I have a  multistep form with validation in it using jquery.validate. Validation is working however user can continue to step 2, even if part 1 doesnt validate client side. The next button is not a submit button, it just unhides step2. I need to disable the next button on each step until all fields in that step validate client side. Form does not submit until last step.  Any help would be appreciated.

here is my .js

```
$("#form1").validate({
    onfocusout : function(element) {
        $(element).valid();
    }
})
```

.html

```
<fieldset id="step1" style="display:block;">
        <label>Unit #</label>
        <input type="text" id="unit" name="unit" placeholder="Unit" class="required"/>
        <label for="unit" class="error"></label>

            etc........

        <button type="button" onclick="changeTab(2);">
            Next
        </button>

</fieldset>
<fieldset id="step2" style="display: none;"> etc.......
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First give your button an id or class like this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="changeTab(2);" id="some-btn">
    Next
</button>
```

Do this when page first loads:

```
$("#some-btn" ).buttonMarkup( "disable" );
```

This will disable button as soon as page is available, when validation is successful just enable it:

```
$("#some-btn" ).buttonMarkup( "enable" );
```

Read more about it in official documentation: http://api.jquerymobile.com/button/#method-disable.

There's one more thing, some jQuery Mobile button type's can only be disabled through custom javascript, read more about it **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/enable-disable-jquery-mobile-button/)**.